# Is there an easy way to do parallel aggregation with a non-commutative operation?

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, aggregate

.NET Framework makes it easy to do parallel aggregation, but according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx), it works for commutative operations only, that is an operation where *f*(*x*, *y*) = *f*(*y*, *x*):

> The .NET implementation of the Parallel Aggregation pattern also expects the operations to be commutative.

I want to aggregate string values using a concatenation, that is a non-commutative operation. A sequential approach looks like this:

```
var result = string.Concat(sequence.Select(this.LongOperation));
```

so if `this.LongOperation` returns successively `Hello`, `World` and `!`, the final result is `HelloWorld!`.

If I use parallel aggregation, the result could be `HelloWorld`, but also `World!Hello`, `!HelloWorld`, etc.

A workaround would be to do something similar to:

```
var result = sequence
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
    .Select(c => new { Index = c.Index, Value = this.LongOperation(c.Value))
    .OrderBy(c => c.Index)
    .Aggregate(seed: string.Empty, func: (prev, current) => prev + current);
```

with the (unimportant, in my particular case) drawback that the entire sequence will be evaluated at `OrderBy` step anyway, without waiting until the aggregation. Another way to write this is:

```
var parts = sequence
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
    .Select(c => new { Index = c.Index, Value = this.LongOperation(c.Value))
    .OrderBy(c => c.Index)
    .Select(c => c.Value);

var result = string.Concat(parts);
```

Am I expected to do that, or is there a simpler way to do the thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`ParallelEnumerable.AsOrdered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413357(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = sequence
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Aggregate(seed: string.Empty, func: (prev, current) => prev + current);
```

The fact that you need to preserve ordering will have a performance hit on your query. As the results need to be aggregated in order, you won't be enjoying the maximum benefit of parallelism, and may sometimes lead to degraded performance over sequential iteration. Having said that, this will do what you're after.

For example, the following code will produce `"[7][35][22][6][14]"` consistently:

```
var result = new [] { 35, 14, 22, 6, 7 }
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(c => "[" + c + "]")
    .Aggregate(seed: string.Empty, func: (prev, current) => prev + current);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

There is a good post about [PLINQ Ordering](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/11/8592301.aspx) by the Parallel Programming Team.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Aggregate is a method on Enumerable.  Consider the case where the type of the accumulator is different from the type of the items. What you would need is a map reduce algorithm.

Comment: @Aron - That is exactly what he's doing with `Aggregate`, He's doing a reduce. He also wants to preserve ordering, according to the said question. That's exactly what he's doing in his example. i

Comment: @Aron I'm sorry, I don't seem to understand why that's wrong?

Comment: It's no longer Parallel. Algorithmically speaking the signature cannot support ordered parallel.

Comment: This is a special case.

Comment: @Aron `AsOrdered` will definitely have a performance impact on the parallelism. But, that said, it doesn't mean that it will make the query sequential. On a per-case basis, this could improve performance over sequential aggregation. Any map-reduce operation which cares for ordering will take a hit.

Comment: The accumulator is a singleton.

Comment: You need to partition and preserve order on an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Aron I do see why this could be potentially problematic with concern to parallelism. Having said that, it does not make my answer "completely wrong". He has a choice, where he can test both ordered "parallelism" agains't sentimentality.

Comment: It's wrong in that it does not forfill the requirements and it fails one silently.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I tested your suggestion and added edited your answer to add the actual test code. It works, so +1 for your answer. I'll try to understand it a bit better tomorrow in order to accept it if it's right.

Comment: @Aron The problem isn't the fact that you can order a parallel enumerable. The problem lays in the fact that the OP is trying to operate in parallel on a set which requires ordering, which is fundamentally not the best approach. I've added a disclaimer to my answer to state that.